# how to do reverse operation in ruby using one variable with out using any built in functions

Tags: ruby

```
str="karhik reddy"
n= str.length
for i in n.downto(0) do // reverse iteration of ruby 
str += str[i].to_s
end
puts str[-n..-1]
```

Is this efficient for larger data sets? Like an array of millions of numbers where you would reverse the complete character set in a book?

Comment: `(n - 1).downto(0) { |i| str << str[i] }`

Comment: if am printing the str value at last it's printing the first string as well as second reverse string combined like  karthik reddy  karthik reddyydder kihtrak

Comment: right now you are not reversing the string but appending a reverse version instead try something like: `s.length.-(1).downto(0) { |i| s << s.slice!(i)}`.  [`String#slice!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-slice-21) will mutate the original string by removing the "slice" then we are just appending it to the tail end of the string. As far as efficiency goes built in `reverse` would be more efficient.

Comment: @engineersmnky ❤ `.-(1)`.

Comment: Your code uses no less than 6 builtin functions, but your subject line says you aren't allowed to use any.

Comment: In Ruby everything's a method call, so not using method calls is going to be out of the question here. What's allowed by your particular definition?

Answer (score 2):

Down to 3 methods:

```
"karhik reddy".each_char.inject(&:prepend)
```

Comment: 4! You are implicitly sending `Symbol#to_proc` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this caveman style with no "built-in functions", the closest you can do is:

```
def primitive_reverse(str)
  out = ''
  i = 0

  while (i < str.length)
    i += 1
    out << str[-i]
  end

  out
end
```

Where technically `String#<<`, `String#[]` and `String#length` are all methods, but without that you're unable to complete this.

Comment: "Caveman style"? Love it. (For extra measure maybe you should use a `for` loop.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I resisted the urge because Ruby is allergic to `for` and it seemed out of place.

Comment: You missed `Integer#<`, `Integer#+`, and `Integer#-@`, which your code also uses ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag More good examples of how this is an impossible exercise without a better definition of "built-in methods".

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the most efficient way should be smth like:

```
> str = "karhik reddy"
> (n = str.length).times { |i| str[i...i], str[n..n] = str[n-1], '' }
> str
#⇒ "ydder kihrak"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this uses 4 "builtin functions", which according to the OP aren't allowed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I took a liberty to rely on what kind of built-in was presented in the original code. I understood that built-in `reverse` and family is not allowed, while `[]`, `[]=`, `length` and `times` are allowed, otherwise we’ll end up writing [tag:c] extension dealing with memory directly.